# ¿Cómo arreglo este problema con una imágen en un Sticky Header (encabezado pegajoso)?

Tags: html, css, animación

Tengo un problema al insertar una imágen en mi Sticky Header o Encabezado dinámico. Aquí se ve en el siguiente GIF:
[image]

Cuando estoy arriba de todo en la web, se encuentra bien el logo, pero cuando bajo, hago scroll y la imágen se tapa por la mitad. Pero sólo pasa con la imágen, porque al bajar, las letras se ajustan. Cómo podría solucionarlo? Gracias.

Códigos:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  if( $(this).scrollTop() > 0 ){
   $('header').addClass('header2');
  } else {
   $('header').removeClass('header2');
  }
 });
 
});
```

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}

body {
 background:#fffffa;
}

header {
width:100%; /* Establecemos que el header abarque el 100% del documento */
overflow:hidden; /* Eliminamos errores de float */
background:#252932;
margin-bottom:20px;
}
 
.wrapper {
width:90%; /* Establecemos que el ancho sera del 90% */
max-width:1000px; /* Aqui le decimos que el ancho máximo sera de 1000px */
margin:auto; /* Centramos los elementos */
overflow:hidden; /* Eliminamos errores de float */
}
 
header .logo {
font-size:50px;
line-height:200px;
float:left;
}
 
header nav {
float:right;
line-height:200px;
}
 
header nav a {
display:inline-block;
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
padding:10px 20px;
line-height:normal;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
-webkit-transition:all 500ms ease;
-o-transition:all 500ms ease;
transition:all 500ms ease;
}
 
header nav a:hover {
background:#f56f3a;
border-radius:50px;
}

.header2 {
 position: fixed;
 height:100px;
}
 
.header2 .logo {
 line-height:100px;
 font-size:30px;
}
 
.header2 nav {
 line-height:100px;
}

.contenido {
 padding-top:100px;
}

.contenido p {
 margin-bottom:1em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
 header .logo,
 header nav {
  width:100%;
  text-align:center; /*Centramos el menu y el logotipo*/
  line-height:100px;
 }
 
 .header2 {
  height:auto;
 }
 
 .header2 .logo,
 .header2 nav {
  line-height:50px;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script src="header.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <header class="header2">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/DKG7QCr.png" alt="">
   </div>
   <nav>
    <a href="#">Inicio</a>
    <a href="#">Foro</a>
    <a href="#">Tienda</a>
    <a href="#">Votar</a>
    <a href="#">Soporte</a>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </header>

 <section class="contenido wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse reiciendis quod libero soluta non laborum quasi ipsam inventore consectetur vel mollitia, quae quam enim molestiae dicta, possimus rerum, dolorem ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse reiciendis quod libero soluta non laborum quasi ipsam inventore consectetur vel mollitia, quae quam enim molestiae dicta, possimus rerum, dolorem ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse reiciendis quod libero soluta non laborum quasi ipsam inventore consectetur vel mollitia, quae quam enim molestiae dicta, possimus rerum, dolorem ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse reiciendis quod libero soluta non laborum quasi ipsam inventore consectetur vel mollitia, quae quam enim molestiae dicta, possimus rerum, dolorem ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse reiciendis quod libero soluta non laborum quasi ipsam inventore consectetur vel mollitia, quae quam enim molestiae dicta, possimus rerum, dolorem ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse reiciendis quod libero soluta non laborum quasi ipsam inventore consectetur vel mollitia, quae quam enim molestiae dicta, possimus rerum, dolorem ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse reiciendis quod libero soluta non laborum quasi ipsam inventore consectetur vel mollitia, quae quam enim molestiae dicta, possimus rerum, dolorem ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse reiciendis quod libero soluta non laborum quasi ipsam inventore consectetur vel mollitia, quae quam enim molestiae dicta, possimus rerum, dolorem ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse reiciendis quod libero soluta non laborum quasi ipsam inventore consectetur vel mollitia, quae quam enim molestiae dicta, possimus rerum, dolorem ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse reiciendis quod libero soluta non laborum quasi ipsam inventore consectetur vel mollitia, quae quam enim molestiae dicta, possimus rerum, dolorem ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse reiciendis quod libero soluta non laborum quasi ipsam inventore consectetur vel mollitia, quae quam enim molestiae dicta, possimus rerum, dolorem ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse reiciendis quod libero soluta non laborum quasi ipsam inventore consectetur vel mollitia, quae quam enim molestiae dicta, possimus rerum, dolorem ipsum.</p>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas utilizando `font-size` para dar tamaño a tu imagen `png`, con lo cual no funciona, deberías usar `height` o `width`.

Tu código:

```
HTML

<div class="logo">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/DKG7QCr.png" alt="">
</div>

CSS

header .logo {
   font-size:50px;
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   line-height:200px;
   float:left;
}

.header2 .logo {
    line-height:100px;
    font-size:30px;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Podría quedar algo así:

```
header .wrapper .logo img {
    height:50px;
    line-height:200px;
    float:left;
}

.header2 .wrapper .logo img {
    line-height:100px;
    height:30px;

}
```

La caja `.logo` si quieres la podrías eliminar, y directamente das el estilo a la imagen `.header2 .wrapper img`

> Te dejo un ejemplo completo como podria quedar:

CSS

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}

body {
    background:#fffffa;
}

.header {
width:100%; /* Establecemos que el header abarque el 100% del documento */
overflow:hidden; /* Eliminamos errores de float */
background:#252932;
height: 200px; line-height: 200px;
}

.wrapper {
width:90%; /* Establecemos que el ancho sera del 90% */
max-width:1000px; /* Aqui le decimos que el ancho máximo sera de 1000px */
margin:auto; /* Centramos los elementos */
overflow:hidden; /* Eliminamos errores de float */
}

.header img {
height: 200px;
float:left;
}

.header nav {
float:right;
}

.header nav a {
display:inline-block;
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
padding:10px 20px;
line-height:normal;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
-webkit-transition:all 500ms ease;
-o-transition:all 500ms ease;
transition:all 500ms ease;
}

.header nav a:hover {
background:#f56f3a;
border-radius:50px;
}

.header2 {
    position: fixed;
    height:100px; line-height: 100px;
}

.header2 img {  
    height: 100px;
}

.contenido {
    padding-top:100px;
}

.contenido p {
    margin-bottom:1em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 950px) {
    .header img,
    .header nav {
        width:100%;
        text-align:center; /*Centramos el menu y el logotipo*/
        line-height:100px;
    }

    .header,.header2 {
        height:auto;
    }

    .header2 img,
    .header2 nav {
        line-height:50px;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<header class="header">
        <div class="wrapper">

            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/DKG7QCr.png" alt="">

            <nav>
                <a href="#">Inicio</a>
                <a href="#">Foro</a>
                <a href="#">Tienda</a>
                <a href="#">Votar</a>
                <a href="#">Soporte</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="contenido wrapper">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse reiciendis quod libero soluta non laborum quasi ipsam inventore consectetur vel mollitia, quae quam enim molestiae dicta, possimus rerum, dolorem.</p>        
    </section>
```

Comment: Hola @D.Bulten, buenas tardes. Introduciendo esos códigos acambio de los que yo tenía, se achica la imágen
https://i.gyazo.com/40ae74c946efc4f901e4b7b2c189f1ba.gif

Comment: 30px realmente es un tamaño muy pequeño, puse esos valores a como estaban tus font-size, pero como puedes ver, ahora si cambia el tamaño de la imagen cuando haces scroll, aunque deberas arreglar un poco el CSS, valores, etc.

Comment: Te he añadido un ejemplo completo, en primer lugar, no debes añadir tu mismo class="header2" en tu `HTML` y he añadido las medidas al header con un line-height, ya que es la caja padre de la imagen y menu que quieres centrar.

Comment: Vale, muchísimas gracias! Ahora sí se ve bien. Pero ahora tengo otro problema, que supongo que es por por parte del código de JS. Cuando cargo la web ya me aparece el header como si hubiese bajado, y tengo que bajar y subir para que aparezca la posición inicial.
Sería así:
https://i.gyazo.com/4eb5bfabc8cb183e6a1283a268169f2c.gif

Comment: Ahh muchísimas gracias! Con ese código CSS que me dejaste ahora sí funciona todo correcto. Muchas gracias por todo D.Bulten! Nos vemos!

Comment: Me alegro amigo, que tengas suerte con tu proyecto. Un saludo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50632/discussion-between-d-bulten-and-nerraden).

Answer (score 1):

Yo empezaría por editar la imagen para poder trabajar bien con ella: quita todo el espacio en blanco que hay alrededor del logo en el propio .gif: 66px por la derecha, 39px por arriba, 40px por la derecha y 50px por debajo. Así puedes controlar bien el tamaño y los márgenes del logo desde el código.

[image: Espacio en blanco de la imagen]

Es el propio espacio en blanco de la imagen (en amarillo) lo que la mantiene abajo. Hay maneras para ajustarlo desde el código, pero es más fácil editar la imagen y tener buena materia prima para trabajar.

Comment: Hola @MarioZ. Gracias por tu ayuda! Ya he logrado solucionar el problema que tenía. Saludos!